# What does 'super().__init__()' mean in python 3.x?

Tags: class, python-3.x, super, metaclass

What is the difference between these two code samples?

1:

```
class SubType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super().__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

2:

```
class SubType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        pass
```

Answer (score 9):

In python 3.x it means calling the  __init__  method of the superclass (i.e. type) (as if it were a method of the current class, SubType, since the current class is a derived of the superclass).

It is the same as calling super(type, self).__init__() in Python 2.x

For example:

```
class type:
       def __init__(self, a):
           print(a)

 class SubType(type):
       def __init__(self, a):
           super().__init__(a)

>> obj = SubType(2) 
2
>>
```

Answer (score 4):

in one case you are calling the `__init__` method of the base class for all classes (i.e. type) - and in th e other you aren't.

Since this method does nothing by default, there is effectively no difference between the two listings.

(What  really performs the class creation magic is the metaclass `__new__` method - and it is not possible to have a new object in Python without calling a native base metaclass'`__new__`method.

Answer (score 0):

Super lets you avoid referring to the base class explicitly, which can be nice. But the main advantage comes with multiple inheritance, where all sorts of [fun stuff](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275) can happen. See the [standard docs on super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) if you haven't already.

Comment: Source: [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576183/11671779)

Answer (score -2):

The code in block 1 will break in Python 2 but will pass in Python 3. The code in block 2 will pass for both.